# debian 9 error connect vpn l2tp

Tags: debian, vpn, l2tp

I have tried the vpn l2tp connection, but I can't connect. I use GUI Network Manager. this is the debug code

```
nm-l2tp[25816] <info>  starting ipsec
Stopping strongSwan IPsec failed: starter is not running
Starting strongSwan 5.5.1 IPsec [starter]...
Loading config setup
Loading conn 'b90b8bb2-cbd9-456c-a33e-b43adc975dec'
found netkey IPsec stack
nm-l2tp[25816] <info>  Spawned ipsec up script with PID 25879.
initiating Main Mode IKE_SA b90b8bb2-cbd9-456c-a33e-b43adc975dec[1] to 103.76.22.130
generating ID_PROT request 0 [ SA V V V V V ]
sending packet: from 192.168.42.162[500] to 103.76.22.130[500] (240 bytes)
sending retransmit 1 of request message ID 0, seq 1
sending packet: from 192.168.42.162[500] to 103.76.22.130[500] (240 bytes)
nm-l2tp[25816] <warn>  Timeout trying to establish IPsec connection
nm-l2tp[25816] <info>  Terminating ipsec script with PID 25879.
Stopping strongSwan IPsec...
destroying IKE_SA in state CONNECTING without notification
establishing connection 'b90b8bb2-cbd9-456c-a33e-b43adc975dec' failed
nm-l2tp[25816] <warn>  Could not establish IPsec tunnel.

(nm-l2tp-service:25816): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_method_invocation_take_error: assertion 'error != NULL' failed
```

can someone help me what happened or fix it? 
i have tried tutorial in [here](https://thomask.sdf.org/blog/2018/01/16/l2tp-vpn-networkmanager-debian-stretch.html) and [here](https://github.com/nm-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp)

Answer (score 0):

Running ./ike-scan.sh script from the second link you provided results in :

```
    sudo ipsec stop
    sudo ./ike-scan.sh 103.76.22.130 | grep SA=
      SA=(Enc=3DES Hash=SHA1 Auth=PSK Group=2:modp1024 LifeType=Seconds LifeDuration(4)=0x00007080)
      SA=(Enc=3DES Hash=SHA1 Auth=PSK Group=14:modp2048 LifeType=Seconds LifeDuration(4)=0x00007080)
      SA=(Enc=AES Hash=SHA1 Auth=PSK Group=2:modp1024 KeyLength=128 LifeType=Seconds LifeDuration(4)=0x00007080)
      SA=(Enc=AES Hash=SHA1 Auth=PSK Group=14:modp2048 KeyLength=128 LifeType=Seconds LifeDuration(4)=0x00007080)
      SA=(Enc=AES Hash=SHA1 Auth=PSK Group=2:modp1024 KeyLength=192 LifeType=Seconds LifeDuration(4)=0x00007080)
      SA=(Enc=AES Hash=SHA1 Auth=PSK Group=14:modp2048 KeyLength=192 LifeType=Seconds LifeDuration(4)=0x00007080)
      SA=(Enc=AES Hash=SHA1 Auth=PSK Group=2:modp1024 KeyLength=256 LifeType=Seconds LifeDuration(4)=0x00007080)
      SA=(Enc=AES Hash=SHA1 Auth=PSK Group=14:modp2048 KeyLength=256 LifeType=Seconds LifeDuration(4)=0x00007080)
```

All of the proposals from that VPN server are considered weak as they are using SHA1 and/or modp1024. Could you try the following phase 1 and 2 algorithms :

- **Phase1 Algorithms** : aes256-sha1-modp2048,aes256-sha1-modp1024!
- **Phase2 Algorithms** : aes256-sha1!

I've picked the two strongest proposals offered by the VPN server for phase 1. The exclamation mark (`!`) is to restrict the VPN client to the specified proposals and not include strongSwan's default proposals. Some VPN servers don't like being flooded with lots of proposals from the client.